# Don't display a button while file don't exists on server - with Flask

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to show a download button *only after* the file is created by my Flask application?
Using PHP, it would probably be something like this:

```
<style>
.hidden{ display:none;}
</style>

<?php
if(!file_exists("path") ){ $class = "hidden" }
  echo "<button type=\"submit\" onclick=\"window.open(\'file.txt\')\">Download!</button>";
?>
```

I tried to use Python code directly in the HTML file:

```
{% if os.path.isfile('file.txt') %}
    <button type="submit" onclick="window.open('file.txt')">Download!</button>
{% else %}
    <button type="submit" class="hidden" onclick="window.open('file.doc')">Download!</button>
{% endif %}
```

But got an error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'os' is undefined
```

**UPDATE**

Full code after @furas reply.
What the code should be doing:

1. Creates a new thread, that will write a file.
2. The template is rendered, with a hidden download button.
3. The file is created
4. The download button became automatically visible - because now the file exists.

However, in the code below, the button keeps hidden after the file is written. The button only shows up if the page is reloaded after the creation of the file.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import threading
import time
import os
global exporting_threads


class ExportingThread(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        
        file = open("file.txt", "w") 
        file.close()


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


@app.route('/')
def index():
    exporting_threads = ExportingThread()
    exporting_threads.start()

    return render_template('index.html', file_exist = os.path.isfile('file.txt'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

index.html, inside the 'templates' folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .hidden{ display:none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    {% if file_exist %}
        <button type="submit" onclick="window.open('file.doc')">Download!</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" class="hidden" onclick="window.open('file.doc')">Download!</button>
    {% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PHP` mix code with HTML and it makes big mess. But Flask tries to keep it separated.

Check if file exits in code before you render template and send only result to template - ie.

```
 return render_string(...., file_exist=os.path.isfile('file.txt'))
```

and in template

```
 {% if file_exist %}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Usually files are in subfolders and you should use

```
 os.path.isfile('subfolder/file.txt')
```

or even

```
 os.path.isfile('/full/path/to/file.txt')
```

---

**EDIT:**

Problem is more complex. Server needs longer time to create file in separated thread so this file doesn't exist yet when server check `isfile()`. It needs JavaScript and AJAX which will periodically send requests to other function (ie. `/check`) and it will send `True` or `False` from `isfile()`.

Minimal working example using pure JavaScript and `XMLHttpRequest` but you can try to write it with `fetch()` or using library `jQuery`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import threading
import time
import os

# delete only for test code
#if os.path.isfile('file.txt'):
#    os.unlink("file.txt")

class ExportingThread(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(5)
       
        file = open("file.txt", "w") 
        file.close()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    exporting_threads = ExportingThread()
    exporting_threads.start()

    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .hidden {display:none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button" type="submit" class="hidden" onclick="window.open('file.doc')">Download!</button>

    <script>

        // ask server if file exists
        function check() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
                
                if(this.responseText == 'True') {
                    // show button
                    document.getElementById("button").classList.remove("hidden");
                    // stop checking 
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                }
              }
            };
        
            xhttp.open("GET", "/check", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
        
        // repeate function `check` every 1000ms (1s)
        var timer = setInterval(check, 1000);
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>''')

@app.route('/check')
def check():
    return str(os.path.isfile('file.txt'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Totaly agree with your answer, just want to expand it - Jinja's philosophy is to only allow as little logic as possible in templates. I suggest to keep your logic in your controller (here function linked to given route).

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, the button does not update its class after the file creation or deletion. The file existence is checked only once - when the template is rendered. The solution below updates the button class, but also creates one new button every 2 seconds.
`@app.route('/')
def index():
 def generate_output():
  while True:
   yield render_template('index.html', file_exist = os.path.isfile('file.txt'))
   time.sleep(2)

 return Response(stream_with_context(generate_output()))`

Comment: why do you use generator? It seems you have very unusual code. I don't know what you try to do but using normal function (without generator) it would recreate template in every request and it would check file in every request. Better show in question your full example code because it will need totally different method.

Comment: @furas Thank you for your reply. I updated the question with full code and trying to make the question clearer.

Comment: there can be other problem - code may runs in different folder then `file.txt` so you have to use correct path `isfile('/full/path/to/file.txt')`

Comment: This could indeed be a problem. However, the button does show up if the page is reloaded after the file creation. I wish for the button to automatically become visible after the file is created, without the need to reload the page.

Comment: now I see what is the problem - thread needs longer time to create file so this file doesn't  exist when main thread checks `isfile()`. You have to create file in main thread - so it will create it before `isfile()` . Or you will have to use `JavaScript` and `AJAX` to periodically asks server if file already exits. And then use `JavaScript` to remove button on page.

Comment: I added example with JavaScript

Comment: Oh my! Thank you sooo much! This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!